# Get environment variables from pseudo-terminal

Tags: bash, go, unix, environment-variables, pty

I have a program that uses https://github.com/creack/pty to create pseudo terminals. Given a command, it creates a file object where you can read and write and it will work as stdin and stdout.

I use a WebSocket to read & write commands to the program. I have configured it to run from the home directory of root user as well as current user based on my selection.

##### Initialise

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "env")
```

##### Set Command Execution path

```golang
cmd.Dir = "/var/root" // for system user
        // (or)
cmd.Dir = "/Users/user_name" // for current user
```

##### Start the command with a pty.

```golang
ptmx, err := pty.Start(cmd) // ptmx is of type *os.File
```

This works fine but when I try to print environment variables, it will not show all respective environment variables for that particular user or root user.

Is there any way to get environment variables from pseudo-terminal for root user/current user?

Comment: There isn't really any such thing as a user's environment variables; each individual process has its own environment, and its own set of environment variables. Many of the environment variables you're used to seeing in a shell session are created during the shell initialization process, e.g. by `export` commands in the user's shell init scripts. But the shell init scripts may do other things than set up environment variables...

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting the expected output is because `env` is not a shell script. At an interactive prompt try running the command your Go program is running. Here is what I see:

```
> /bin/sh env
/usr/bin/env: /usr/bin/env: cannot execute binary file
```

Try running `/bin/sh -c env` instead. However, since your command does not contain any shell syntax and does nothing more than execute the `env` binary you don't need `/bin/sh` at all. Just exec `env`.

Also, you seem to be under some misconceptions. There is no such thing as "user environment variables". Similarly, a pty does not have env vars. Environment variables are private to each process (and a pty is not a process).

It is true that interactive shells may set env vars by automatically reading various shell config files such as `~/.bashrc` before showing the first prompt but I don't think that's what you're referring to since your `/bin/sh -c env` won't start an interactive shell; even though its stdin and stdout are attached to a pty.